# How to use google map in ionic cordova?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, google-maps, geolocation, ionic-framework

I added the google map plugin to my project with this command:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation
```

after i use this tutorial http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/uzngt ,i use in my page index.html but when i move this code in other page this code is dosen't worked

in the page index.html

```
 <html ng-app="starter">
  <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
        <title></title>

        <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

        IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
        <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">


        ionic/angularjs js
        <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/ionic-datepicker/dist/ionic-datepicker.bundle.min.js"></script>

        cordova script (this will be a 404 during development)
        <script src="js/ng-cordova-oauth.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="js/ngStorage.min.js"></script>


        your app's js 
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/services.js"></script>

        <script src="js/Controllers/inscription.js"></script>
        <script src="js/Controllers/Categories.js"></script>
        <script src="js/Controllers/SousCategories.js"></script>
        <script src="js/Controllers/Evenement.js"></script>
        <script src="js/Controllers/RechercheEvent.js"></script>

        <script src="js/service/services.js"></script>

    google maps javascript
    <script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB16sGmIekuGIvYOfNoW9T44377IU2d2Es&sensor=true"></script>

  </head>
  <body ng-controller="carteController">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark" >
      <h1 class="title">Map</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
    </ion-content>
    <ion-footer-bar class="bar-dark">
      <a ng-click="centerOnMe()" class="button button-icon icon ion-navigate">Find Me</a>
    </ion-footer-bar>
  </body>
</html>
```

in the page carte.html

```
<html ng-app="starter">
  <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
        <title></title>

        <link href="../lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above -->
        <link href="/css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">


        <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
        <script src="../lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="../lib/ionic-datepicker/dist/ionic-datepicker.bundle.min.js"></script>

        <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
        <script src="../js/ng-cordova-oauth.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/ngStorage.min.js"></script>


        <!-- your app's js  -->
        <script src="../js/app.js"></script>
         <script src="../js/services.js"></script>



    <!-- google maps javascript -->
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB16sGmIekuGIvYOfNoW9T44377IU2d2Es&sensor=true"></script>

  </head>
  <body ng-controller="carteController">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark" >
      <h1 class="title">Map</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
    </ion-content>
    <ion-footer-bar class="bar-dark">
      <a ng-click="centerOnMe()" class="button button-icon icon ion-navigate">Find Me</a>
    </ion-footer-bar>
  </body>
</html>
```

my controller app.js

```
facebookExample.controller('carteController', function($scope, $ionicLoading,$cordovaGeolocation,$compile) {

          function initialize() {
              console.log("fonction googleMap");
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.07493,-89.381388);

            var mapOptions = {
              center: myLatlng,
              zoom: 16,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
                mapOptions);

            //Marker + infowindow + angularjs compiled ng-click
            var contentString = "<div><a ng-click='clickTest()'>Click me!</a></div>";
            var compiled = $compile(contentString)($scope);

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              content: compiled[0]
            });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: myLatlng,
              map: map,
              title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
              infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });

            $scope.map = map;
          }
//        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

          $scope.centerOnMe = function() {
            if(!$scope.map) {
              return;
            }

            $scope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
              content: 'Getting current location...',
              showBackdrop: false
            });

            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
              $scope.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
              $scope.loading.hide();
            }, function(error) {
              alert('Unable to get location: ' + error.message);
            });
          };

          $scope.clickTest = function() {
            alert('Example of infowindow with ng-click')
          };

        });
```

my error:

[image]

Comment: nothing is display in console :(

Comment: Have you whitelisten the Google url? On the other hand: It is better to use a native map, use a plugin.

Comment: what is meant by using a "native" map? can you give an example?

Comment: to get maps to work for me I had to edit the index.html to be like the following in the meta http-equiv tag:    'unsafe-inline' https://*.googleapis.com; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://*.googleapis.com        ...in addition to white listing the following: *.google.com, *.googleapis.com, *.gstatic.com

Comment: i don't understand !!!! what's my problem please,how to be resolved